# Why is this elastic search query with must clause not returning any documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble getting this elastic search query to return the data I'd expect it to return. This is my query:

```
curl -XGET '0.0.0.0:9200/local/candidate/_search?routing=company_1_candidates&pretty' -d '
{
    "query":{
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "fields": [
                        "candidate_name",
                        "candidate_city",
                        "candidate_country"
                    ],
                    "query": "j",
                    "type": "phrase_prefix"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "company_id": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "candidate_city": "Rotterdam"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

When I run this query with only the `company_id` term in the must clause, I'm finding this record:

```
{"candidate_name":"J Kennis","candidate_id":2,"candidate_tags":[],"candidate_city":"Rotterdam","candidate_country":"Nederland","company_id":1}
```

But when I include the `"candidate_city": "Rotterdam"` bit in the query, it returns zero results. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the candidate_city field is being indexed with an analyzer that includes the token analyzer "lower", but the term filter is un-analyzed.

If you change your filter to

  `"term": {"candidate_city": "rotterdam"}`

or

  `"match": {"candidate_city": "Rotterdam"}`

you'll probably get the document back.